# Input type date is not working in android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, datepicker

I am trying to Use an Html5 input type date control in an android app. But the date picker won't pop up on some mobiles. I tried installing the `apk` on a Micromax canvas and the `datepicker` worked fine there, whereas this didn't Happen on Sony Xperia. Is there something that I need to include in the code that I'm missing. I have included the code below. The Input type date has been added through a jquery code.
Thanks, everyone in advance

```
msg1 = "<tr style='font-size:initial;font-family:initial'><td><input type='checkbox'/></td>\n\
<td style='width:16%'>" + results.rows.item(j).name + " </td><td style='width:6%'>
" + enddate+ "</td>\n\
<td>
<input style ='font-size:initial;font-family:initial;border-style:hidden' type ='date' 
name = 'actstart' / > < /td>\n\
<td><input type='date' style='font-size:initial;font-family:initial;
border-style:hidden'name='actend'></td >\n\
<td> < div id = 'sliderdiv' > < input type = 'range'  data - highlight = 'true'
 style = ' margin-top: 15px;margin-bottom: 15px;float:left' id = '" + j + "' 
 name = 'slider-1' id = 'slider-1' data - highlight = 'true' min = '0' max = '100' 
 value = '" + results.rows.item(j).percent + "' />\n\
 < span  id = 'sliderspan' text = '" + results.rows.item(j).percent + "'  
 style = 'width: 10px;display: inline-block;height: 5px;'>"+results.rows.item(j).percent+"
 < /span>< /div>< /td>< td > \n\
 < input type = 'text' style = 'margin-left:10px;border-style:hidden' maxlength ='75'/></td>\n\
 < /tr>";
  var temp="#tsk"+k;
 document.querySelector(temp).innerHTML += msg1;
```

Comment: I can't really make much of the code there. Are you initialising the datepicker via jQuery after the page loads?

Comment: no its just an html5 control so it need not be initialized i guess.It does work on my Micromax Canvas but not on sony or Nokia :(